# How can I protect password on PHP Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have simple sign in form in my project on PHP Symfony.
But I found this problem.

when I will use this command

```
$("#signin_password").val()
```

in Chrome it shows me password not secured.

How can I to protect user password in this way?

Comment: You cannot, users are allowed to read their passwords fields. It would be difficult to post them without that access. Now, if you run untrusted javascript in that page, **that** is the problem, not basic UA-functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to never show a raw password on the page.  What's more, you should never store a raw password in a database or in any other medium.

The best method is to use one-way encryption to store all passwords, and in order to check a password, you would simply compare the "encypted string" to what is stored in the database.

Because you are using symfony 1.4, I'd suggest checking out the [sfGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin) for a ready-made solution.